# Cannot merge two sorted singly linked list, because of "type object '_Node' has no attribute '_element'"

Tags: python, function, data-structures, merge, singly-linked-list

I'm making my own merge_list function. I already made class SList(), and class _Node(). But when I enter two sorted lists in merge_list, merge_list function cannot compare the two node's values, with showing `type object '_Node' has no attribute '_element'`, but class _Node have _element attribute(I also try element, but it doesn't work either). What's wrong with my function??

this is my partial code for `class SList()`, and `class _Node()` and full code of `merge_list`

```
class SList:
    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, element, next=None):
            self._element = element
            self._next = next

        def element(self):
            return self._element

        def next(self):
            return self._next

        def set_element(self, element):
            self._element = element

        def set_next(self, next):
            self._next = next

    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self._head = head

    def insert_first(self, element):
        self._head = self._Node(element, self._head)

    def insert_after(self, element, p):
        new_node = self._Node(element, p.next())
        p._next = new_node
```

.
.
.
and my merge_list function

```
def merge_list(s1, s2):
    s3 = SList()
    s3._Node(None, None)
    prev = s3

    while s1 != None and s2 != None:
        if s1._Node._element<= s2._Node._element: # this line is the problem
            prev.next = s1
            s1 = s1.next
        else:
            prev.next = s2
            s2 = s2.next
        prev = prev.next

    if s1 == None:
        prev.next = s2
    elif s2 == None:
        prev.next = s1

    return s3.next
```

After I made this function, I entered two sorted list like this and call the merge_list function

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    s1 = SList()
    s1.insert_first(1)
    s1.insert_first(3)
    s1.insert_first(5)
    s1.insert_first(7)
    s1.insert_first(9)
    s1.insert_first(11)
    s1.insert_first(13)
    print(f"s1 :", s1)


    s2 = SList()
    s2.insert_first(2)
    s2.insert_first(4)
    s2.insert_first(6)
    print(f"s2 : ", s2)
    merge_list(s1, s2)
```

and the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
s1 : 13 -> 11 -> 9 -> 7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 1 -> None: 7 element(s)
s2 :  6 -> 4 -> 2 -> None: 3 element(s)
  File "", line 334, in <module>
    merge_list(s1, s2)
  File "", line 151, in merge_list
    if s1._Node._element<= s2._Node._element:
AttributeError: type object '_Node' has no attribute '_element'
```

It seems that s1, s2 lists are successfully created, but cannot compare the node's value. What's the problem with merge_list function??

Comment: I suppose it has to do with the difference between class attributes and instances attributes ?

Comment: What do I have to do then???

Comment: You need to store the different nodes in an attribute of SList. Since I don't have your full code, I don't even know what ``s1.insert_first(1)``does.
Also, if you can use Attrs library that would help you a bunch.

Comment: @JYP, paste full code please. Your code does not include `insert_first` method per se.

Comment: I add insert_firtst method...what's wrong with my code??

Comment: @JYP Any though on the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's go step by step

## Code Analysis :

```
class SList:
    class _Node:
```

**note** Why define the Node class in the SList class ? This isn't common practice , unless you never wish to access the Node from outside the Slist (and even then)

```
        def __init__(self, element, next=None):
            self._element = element
            self._next = next

        def element(self):
            return self._element

        def next(self):
            return self._next

        def set_element(self, element):
            self._element = element

        def set_next(self, next):
            self._next = next
```

**note** Init/getters and setters. Up until now, everything makes sense . However , I would personally prefer the library @attrs. But we will get onto that later.

```
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self._head = head

    def insert_first(self, element):
        self._head = self._Node(element, self._head)

    def insert_after(self, element, p):
        new_node = self._Node(element, p.next())
        p._next = new_node


def merge_list(s1, s2):
    s3 = SList()
    s3._Node(None, None)
    prev = s3

    while s1 != None and s2 != None:
        if s1._Node._element<= s2._Node._element: # this line is the problem
```

Well this simply won't work for the reasons aforementioned in the comments : the class _Node doesn't have an _element attribute. The instances do though.

```
            prev.next = s1
```

`prev`is `s3`which is `SList`therefore shouldn't have an attribute next ?

```
            s1 = s1.next
        else:
            prev.next = s2
            s2 = s2.next
        prev = prev.next

    if s1 == None:
        prev.next = s2
    elif s2 == None:
        prev.next = s1

    return s3.next
```

## First attempt to help ( NB : This is a working solution based on what OP provided, and not an attempt to write clean code.)

```
class _Node:
    def __init__(self, element, next=None):
        self._element = element
        self._next = next

    @property
    def element(self):
        return self._element
    @property
    def next(self):
        return self._next

    def set_element(self, element):
        self._element = element

    def set_next(self, next):
        self._next = next

class SList:
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self._head = _Node(head)

    @property
    def head(self):
        return self._head 

    def insert_first(self, element):
        self._head = _Node(element, self._head)

    def insert_after(self, element, p):
        new_node = _Node(element, p.next())
        p._next = new_node

def merge_list(s1, s2):
    s3 = SList()
    prev = s3._head
    head_s1 = s1._head
    head_s2 = s2._head

    while (head_s1._element != None) and (head_s2._element != None):
        if head_s1._element<= head_s2._element: # this line is the problem
            prev.set_next(head_s1)
            head_s1 = head_s1.next
        else:
            prev.set_next(head_s2)
            head_s2 = head_s2.next
        prev = prev.next

    if head_s1 == None:
        prev.set_next(head_s1)
    elif head_s2 == None:
        prev.set_next(head_s2)

    return s3
```

Comment: Please try to understand my comments, and refactor the solution to your needs. If you wish for me (or someone else) to provide a "cleaner" way to do what you are doing, please shout :)